# How to compute the Integral of this exponentials?

Tags: integration

In my calculations I stumbled upon the following integral which is a little bit daunting. I couldn't come up with the proper variable substitution solution. Can anybody please explain using which method I can calculate the following integral ?:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-\epsilon}
\exp\left(\, -e^{-\epsilon}
\left[\, 1 + \exp\left(\, u_{2}\ -\ u_{1}\,\right)\,\right]\,\right) \,\mathrm{d}\epsilon
$$

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many already suggested, use the substitution

$$y = e^{-\epsilon} ~~~~~~~ \text{d}y = -e^{-\epsilon}\ \text{d}\epsilon$$

The extrema will now run from $+\infty$ to $0$:

$$\large \int_{+\infty}^0 \underbrace{-e^{-\epsilon}\ \text{d}\epsilon}_{\text{d}y}\ e^{\overbrace{e^{-\epsilon}}^{y}\ A}$$

Hence, exchanging the extrema and the sign:

$$\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-y A}\ \text{d}y$$

Where $A = 1 + e^{u_2 - u_1}$

Result is trivial and it's

$$\boxed{\frac{1}{A} = \frac{1}{1 + e^{u_2 - u_1}}}$$

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I chose it as the answer since it uses regular substitution rather than integration by parts.

Comment: @Mohammadreza thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: examining the expression for a possible integration by parts quickly reveals that: $$\dfrac{\mathrm d e^{-c e^{-\epsilon}}}{\mathrm d \epsilon\qquad}= ce^{-\epsilon}e^{-ce^{-\epsilon}}$$ Where $c=(1+e^{u_2-u_1})$

Answer (score 0):

Sub $x=e^{-\epsilon}$.  This is then

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{-a x} = \frac1{a} $$

where $a=1+e^{u_2-u_1}$.

Comment: Thank you Ron. I believe your's and Alan's answer are the same. I chose his answer since it was well detailed. I also voted yours up.